# Simple question about media screen. How to use both width and height (each one depends on other)?

Tags: css

So what I have is one with `max-width: 992px`, another is `max-height: 732px` **and** `max-width: 992px`. What I want is to media screen do something only if both height and width are lower than max.
I have this:

```
@media screen and (max-height: 753px) and (max-width: 992px){
}
```

How it should be?

Nvm, just place `@media screen` inside another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested media queries. Something like this

```css
@media (max-width:992px) {
    @media (max-height:432px) {
        .test-div{
            background-color: blue;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works well in your case

```
@media screen and (max-height: 753px) , screen and (max-width: 992px) { 
....
....
}
```

[Check Documentation Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score 1):

You should use only `end` in between your `height` and `width` property

```
@media (max-width: 992px) and (max-height: 732px) {
  /* CSS stuff */
}
```